# Is there a way to set up an Ethereum wallet without downloading the whole blockchain?

Tags: wallets

(noobie question) I've tried using Mist and/or Ethereum-Wallet, but the tried to node downloaded > 30GB of blockchain data. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using an online wallet such as [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/). You will be able to create an account, send transactions and deploy a contract.

Comment: Thabks, how about a local version? Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think if it exists light clients at the moment. I know a lot of people are expecting it because many mobile applications could be develop to interact with the Ethereum blockchain without tiers. Otherwise, you could execute Mist with geth in fast mode mode which will reduce the blockchain data to 7 Gb

Answer (score 8):

Jaxx.io is an Ethereum (and other cryptocurrency) wallet that is stored locally on your computer without downloading the whole blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

[Metamask](https://metamask.io/) browser extension works as a hot wallet.