# Is it possible to use a multisig wallet without downloading the whole blockchain?

Tags: wallets, light-clients

Related:

- [What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs)
- [Is there a way to set up an Ethereum wallet without downloading the whole blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8979/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-an-ethereum-wallet-without-downloading-the-whole-blockc)

Is it possible to have it installed and use some clever features (multisig) without downloading *(syncing)* the blockchain?

[image]

Comment: @Ismael put it in `related` section, that question does not answer as `use some clever features (multisig)` - unless MEW supports multisig?

Comment: You should correct the title to "It is possible to use a multisig wallet without downloading the whole blockchain?", else it is confusing.

Comment: I do not agree, what if I want to deploy a contract? I want to use features, I don't want to store blockchain...

Answer (score 2):

You will need a light wallet. you have choice between :

geth as [Light Client](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/17/whoa-geth-1-5/) with ETHereum wallet or use instead jaxx.

1)`geth --light` //it syncs quickely it gets only the current state (small disk space)

Alternatively use:

`cd /Applications/Ethereum\ Wallet.app/Contents/MacOS/
./Ethereum\ Wallet --light`

[image]
[image]

2) [JAxx](https://jaxx.io)

Comment: What are the disk space usages for these options?